# Forward request to another controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'd like to know if there is a way I can forward a request from one controller to another without actually changing the URL in the browser.

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/myurl"})
public ModelAndView handleMyURL(){

    if(somecondition == true)
    //forward to another controller but keep the url in the browser as /myurl
}
```

examples that I found online were redirecting to another url which was causing other controllers to handle that. I don't want to change the URL.

Comment: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061294/can-i-chain-two-spring-controllers-together-each-doing-partial-retrieval-of-dat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of forwarding, you may just call the controller method directly after getting a reference to it via autowiring. Controllers are normal spring beans:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
  @Autowired OtherController otherController;
  @RequestMapping("/myurl")
  public String handleMyURL(Model model) {
    otherController.doStuff();
    return ...;
  }
}

@Controller
public class OtherController {
  @RequestMapping("/doStuff")
  public String doStuff(Model model) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to return a `String` instead of `ModelAndView`, and the String being the forward url.

```
@RequestMapping({"/myurl"})
public String handleMyURL(Model model) {
    if(somecondition == true)
        return "forward:/forwardURL";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know "forward" of a request will be done internally by the servlet, so there will not be a second request and hence the URL should remain the same. Try using the following code.

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/myurl"})
public ModelAndView handleMyURL(){

    if(somecondition == true){
        return new ModelAndView("forward:/targetURL");
    }
}
```