# Spring JPA - Batch Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, batch-processing

I would like to implement batch request handling in Java (Spring Data JPA, Hibernate, Lombok).

I have some @RestControllers. This is the request body for batch request:

```
[
  {
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
    "method": "GET",
    "URL": "/something/",
    "body": {}
  },
  {
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/something2/",
    "body": {}
  }
]
```

I need to dynamically determine the correct RestController depending on **METHOD** and **URL**, which must process the request from batch. The response must look like this:

```
{
  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001": {
    "status": "OK",
    "data": {}
  },
  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002": {
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "data": {}
  }
}
```

I already have the correct implementation of classes for batchRequests, batchResponse, and base BatchController, but I need to add dynamic request processing.

Thank you in advance for tips on how to do that.

**Update - What is implemented:**

- BatchRequest class:

```
    package _batch;  
      
    import jakarta.persistence.Transient;  
    import lombok.Getter;  
    import lombok.Setter;  
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;  
      
    import java.util.UUID;  
      
    @Getter  
    @Setter  
    public class BatchRequest {  
      
        @Transient  
      private UUID id;  
      
        @Transient  
      private RequestMethod method;  
      
        @Transient  
      private String url;  
      
        @Transient  
      private Object body;  
      
    }
```

- BatchResponse class:

```
    package _batch;  
      
    import jakarta.persistence.Transient;  
    import lombok.Getter;  
    import lombok.Setter;  
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;  
      
    @Getter  
    @Setter  
    public class BatchResponse {  
      
        @Transient  
      private HttpStatus status;  
      
        @Transient  
      private Object data;  
      
    }
```

- BatchWebController class:

```
    package _batch;  
      
    import EventWebController;  
    import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;  
    import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;  
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;  
    import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;  
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;  
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;  
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;  
      
    import java.util.*;  
      
    @RestController  
    @PreAuthorize("@caller.isAuthenticated()")  
    @Tag(name = "_Batch", description = "Controller for handling batch requests")  
    @SecurityRequirement(name = "Microsoft Entra")  
    public class BatchWebController {  
      
        @Autowired  
      EventWebController eventWebController;  
      
      
        @PostMapping("/batch")  
        public Map<UUID, BatchResponse> processBatchRequest(@RequestBody List<BatchRequest> batchRequests) {  
      
            Map<UUID, BatchResponse> batchResponseList = new HashMap<>();  
      
            for (BatchRequest request : batchRequests) {  
      
                BatchResponse batchResponse = new BatchResponse();  
                
                --->> batchResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
                --->> batchResponse.setData(eventWebController.getEvents());
      
                batchResponseList.put(request.getId(), batchResponse);  
      
            }  
      
            return batchResponseList;  
      
        }  
      
    }
```

- And there is a look on EventWebController:

```
    package event;

    import NotFoundException;
    import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;
    import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.UUID;

    @RestController
    @Tag(name = "Events")
    @SecurityRequirement(name = "Microsoft Entra")
    public class EventWebController {

        @Autowired
        private EventService eventService;

        @GetMapping("/applications/events")
        public List<Event> getEvents() {
            return eventService.get();
        }

        @GetMapping("/applications/events/{id}")
        public Event getEvent(@PathVariable UUID id) throws NotFoundException {
            return eventService.get(id);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It would help to share the code you've made regarding the processing of these requests, since that's the area of concern.

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you are looking for. What do you mean by 'batch requests'? Are you simply supposed to receive the payload and send the requests to appropriate REST endpoints? In such case, any HTTP client will work for you. Just use `RestTemplate` since you're using Spring already. You can couple that with Spring Batch for a declarative approach if you want, though it's probably an overkill

Comment: @crizzis I want to implement something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching. So, to send multiple API requests in just one API call.

Comment: @Rogue I have Implemented only basic things right now. See updated question :)

Comment: In that case, my comment still stands. Why inject `EventWebController`, though? Just use `RestTemplate` to call your own app. If you want to avoid the network overhead, you might want to have a look at [`HandlerAdapter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324506/1092818)